# How to set Primary Key and Foreign key in Redis

Tags: c#-4.0, redis

I have created two hash key value pair in **Redis** named `Person` and `Account`. The `Person` key has the first name and last name of the person and the `Account` Key contains account type and savings. Now I want to do a join similar to SQL joins(`inner join`) to retrieve the account type and savings of each person from both the hash values.

Kindly help me out to find a solution to this problem and could anyone please help me in setting a primary key and foreign key in Redis hash key value pairs.

Comment: Redis has no joins - you need to read each key separately.

Comment: .Thanks for your reply.We are aware that Redis has no joins.Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: @Smith, could you show the commands (or type of values) you're using to store the data?